# Windows 8 won't boot after installing Ubuntu, 'device format invalid'

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Windows 8 installed on a partition. Installed Ubuntu 12.10 on another, it works fine, but when I try to boot Windows 8, it says

```
error: device format "ldm/84ec4a8-84ad-11e1-a109-002655b2e743/Volume1" invalid: must be (f|h), with 0 <= N < 128.
Press any key to continue...
```

And then on the next screen

```
A disk error occured
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

Comment: Did you use and external drive?

Comment: @Farid Nope, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have the same problem. It's not that easy to make Windows 8 dual-bootable with another OS. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system) should help you (Answer 1). But you have to re-install Windows to do that, and that's where the next problem came up for me: Trying to install Win8 from DVD, the installer doesn't recognize partitions any more... I think formatting the Windows Partition (C, in most cases) could be a solution, but I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Is the LDM from dynamic partitions?
Dynamic also on gpt as LDM

GRUB2 2.00 recognizes defunct LDM headers from old dynamic partitions

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1061255

What do these Windows tools show?
EASEUS Partition Master

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Partition Wizard

http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html